# when I refresh the page, not the page loads. Angularjs + Nodejs

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express

When I reload the page by pressing F5, the page does not reload.
I am using Node.js, Express Js and AngularJS.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es-ar">
    <head>
        <title>My web</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href="stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <!--Maps-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcKGv4lLvSO6F8dKq976CT_zQPiRVcDRQ&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendors/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendors/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendors/ui-leaflet.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.1/leaflet.css" />

        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body class="backgroundGrayLight" ng-app="Index" ng-controller="indexController">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default startNav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" ng-click="btnCollapseNavBar()">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left formSearch" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <a class="btnSearch" href="" close-collapse><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
                </form>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="btnSignRoot" ng-show="viewBtnEnter">

                    <li uib-dropdown role="presentation">
                        <a uib-dropdown-toggle ng-show="viewBtnEnter" id="formLogin"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Iniciar sesión</a>
                        <!-- action="/login" method="post"  -->
                        <form class="form-horizontal uib-dropdown-menu loginForm" aria-labelledby="formLogin">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" ng-model="formData.email" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" ng-model="formData.password" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="recoveryPassword">
                                        <a class="text-center" href="/recoveryPassword" close-collapse>Olvidé mi contraseña</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="error">
                                        <p class="text-center" ng-show="msgErrorLogin" close-collapse>Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrecta</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary submitLogIn" ng-click="login()" close-collapse>Iniciar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/signin" ng-show="viewBtnEnter" close-collapse><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Registrarse</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse menu" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-menu" aria-expanded="false" ng-click="btnCollapseMenu()">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <collapse-left></collapse-left>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse menuNav" id="navbar-collapse-menu">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menuRight">

                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a class="btn" href="/contact" close-collapse style="background-color: #000;">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                    <li uib-dropdown role="presentation">
                        <a uib-dropdown-toggle class="btn" href="" style="background-color: #000;" id="idMyAccountDropdown">Mi cuenta</a>
                        <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu optionMyAccount" aria-labelledby="idMyAccountDropdown">
                            <li><a href="/manageAccount" close-collapse>Administrar mi cuenta</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="loadModalCreateShop()" close-collapse>Crear comercio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/manageMyShops" close-collapse>Administrar mis negocios</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="/manageWeb" close-collapse>Administrar web</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/logout" close-collapse>Cerrar sesión</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="backgroundGrayLight">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer" ng-controller="yearCopyright">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p class="text-center">&copy; {{year}}</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/indexController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/formSignInController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/contactController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/recoveryPasswordController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/manageAccountController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/pModalMsgInstanceController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/homepageController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/shopsController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/shopSelectedController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/createShopController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/loadImagesController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/loadVideoController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/shopPaymentController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/manageMyShopsController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/editShopController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/manageWebController.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/onErrorSrc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputName.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputLastName.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputUserName.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputEmailWithRepeat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputPassword.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputPasswordWithRepeat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputEmail.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputSubject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputComment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/pModal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/collapseLeft.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/closeCollapse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputShopName.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputAddress.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputAddressNumber.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputProvinceCity.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputPhoneNumber.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputLinkWebsite.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/shopCommentaryMain.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/inputNewCommentaryShop.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/serveCategories.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/serveShopData.js"></script>

    <!-- Vendors -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendors/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendors/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendors/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendors/checklist-model.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

indexController.js

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {    
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'carouselImg'
        })

        .when('/signin', {
            templateUrl: 'views/signIn.html',
            controller: 'formSignInController'
        })

        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        })

        .when('/recoveryPassword', {
            templateUrl: 'views/recoveryPassword.html',
            controller: 'recoveryPasswordController'
        })

        .when('/manageAccount', {
            templateUrl: 'views/manageAccount.html',
            controller: 'manageAccountController'
        })

        .when('/homepage', {
            templateUrl: 'views/homepage.html',
            controller: 'homepageController'
        })

        .when('/shop/:itemId/cat/:categoryId', {
            templateUrl: 'views/shops.html',
            controller: 'shopsController'
        })

        .when('/shop/:shopName', {
            templateUrl: 'views/shopSelected.html',
            controller: 'shopSelectedController'
        })

        .when('/manageMyShops', {
            templateUrl: 'views/manageMyShops.html',
            controller: 'manageMyShopsController'
        })

        .when('/manageMyShops/id/:shopId', {
            templateUrl: 'views/editShop.html',
            controller: 'editShopController'
        })

        .when('/manageWeb', {
            templateUrl: 'views/manageWeb.html',
            controller: 'manageWebController'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/main'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); }]);
```

express.js

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(io) {

    var app = express();

    /**
    * Connect to our database
    */

    require(__dirname + '/passport')(passport);

    /**
    * Set up our express application
    */
    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    /* 
    * Required for passport
    */
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'vidyapathaisalwaysrunning',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    })); // session secret
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

    /*
    * Routes
    */
    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes')(app, passport, router, io); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

    /**
    * Development Settings
    */
    if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
        // This covers serving up the index page
        app.use(express.static(path.join('./public')));

        app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
            console.error(err.stack);
            res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
        });
    }

    /**
    * Production Settings
    */
    if ('production' == app.get('env')) {
        app.use(express.static(path.join('./public')));
    }

    //module.exports = app;
    return app;
}
```

index.server.routes.js

```
    app.get(['/homepage', '/recoveryPassword', '/manageAccount', '/shop/:itemId/cat/:categoryId', '/shop/:shopName', '/manageMyShops', '/manageMyShops/id/:shopId', '/manageWeb'], isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        //res.redirect(here req.path) -> Infinite loop
        res.end();    
    });

    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }

        // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
        res.redirect('/');
    }
```

- app (server side)

  - controllers
  - routes
- public

  - /images
  - /js
  - /stylesheets
  - /views
  - index.html

The error occurs with all pages.
I want to make user control for certain sections of the website.
When I press f5, if the user is logged you should be redirected to the page you want to access. example: /homepage + f5 -> isLoggedIn(...)? /homepage : /index.html

Thanks.

Comment: Just a bit more information. You go to the index and it works fine?

Comment: could you be more specific? when you say "the page doesn't reload", which page? all pages?

Comment: @Dreamlines
Any idea. Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLi Any idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't much to go off of, I'll throw the obvious fix out first.

Your routing isn't set up to handle a single page app.

Angular's router is swapping views in and out of the index page when you route around in it, but you never actually leave that first page. This is the desired behavior for a single page app.

If you refresh on a page such as index.com/go/to/path, you're telling you browser to actually go to to that path index.com/go/to/path.

Angular has no idea about this and it's routing only handles the paths tossed around on index.com.

if you use nginx, add this to your location:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

The solution would be similar, if not the same, in apache (dont know off the top of my head).

What it does is it redirects all of those app.com/paths/more/paths to app.com/

There, angular will read the /paths/more/paths and load the proper view.

Comment: As could be configured to behave as an single page app? And, Where I have to configure try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'index.html'));
```

it will redirect to index.html when you press f5.

Comment: > Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Website\App\app\routes\public\views\path.html' The route should be 'C:\...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Website\App\public\views\path.html'

Comment: if you want to move one directory upward. try this './public'

Comment: @chirag I finally solved as follows:

    <head>
      <title>My web</title>
      <base href="/index.html">
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>

index.server.routes.js

     app.get(['/homepage', '/recoveryPassword', '/manageAccount', '/shop/:itemId/cat/:categoryId', '/shop/:shopName', '/manageMyShops', '/manageMyShops/id/:shopId', '/manageWeb'], isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
            res.redirect('index.html#/' + req.path);
        });

And the rest, all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
  res.sendFile('www/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```