# How to handle routes that have # in nodejs with expressjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

The question is related to: [when I refresh the page, not the page loads. Angularjs + Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447777/when-i-refresh-the-page-not-the-page-loads-angularjs-nodejs)

But in this case I disable html5mode and , therefore the url the symbol appears #. I want to have control access to certain sections of the code that I show below, but do not know how to handle the #

```
app.get(['/homepage', '/recoveryPassword', '/manageAccount', '/shop/:itemId/cat/:categoryId', '/shop/:shopName', '/manageMyShops', '/manageMyShops/id/:shopId', '/manageWeb'], isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        res.end();    
    });
```

Comment: A url  hash ( `#xxxxx` ) doesn't get sent to server, it is only used by the browser. Nothing to do with angular.... just how hashes work

Comment: It is unusual to have endpoint names with special character values in them. To simplify things - you should be able to add in a `layer` to the expressJS middleware to convert '#'  to something, a unique word or what. Then register your endpoint accordingly. If you don't mind alternative I can cheep in my idea as an answer for you.

Comment: @SamuelToh Please give me a help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am reluctant to post this because I think this is NOT a real solution to OP's problem. To me this is a hack, so use it at your own risk.

To start with - it is unconventional for REST URL to have special characters like '#' in them. While I believe there is no standard way of naming the endpoints but it is recommended to make sure the URLs follow these rules;

1. all lower-case (because url are not case-sensitive)
2. no special characters
3. no camel case

Anyway, my approach is.

On the server code;

1. Assuming you are defining a path `/config#` then replace the '#' char with something unique e.g. `_bbb` Unique enough? you judge, just make sure it doesn't clash with other endpoints.
2. Add an express layer to decode the URL's special character and replace the special character with the unique word you have given in point 1. (This will be more clear when you see the code).

Client code:

1. Encode the URL. Why? Because URL can't have '#', because it is a reserved character. So it has to be encoded as '%23' instead.

**Example:**

**Client:**

```
"use strict";
let request = require("request");

let req = {
    url: `localhost:4444/${encodeURIComponent('config#')}`,
    proxy: 'http://localhost:4444',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

request(req, function (err, res, body) {
    this.config = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("response => " + this.config);
});
```

**Server:**

```
"use strict";
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var config = require('config');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let decoded_url = decodeURIComponent(req.url);
    req.url = decoded_url.replace('#', '_bbb');
    next();
});

app.get('/config_bbb', function(req, res){
    res.json('{name: test}');
});


// Start the server
app.set('port', 4444);

app.listen(app.get('port'), "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log('started');
});
```

**Output:**

> response => {name: test}

The idea here is. When the client calls the endpoint, yes the URL is still  with `/config#` but you encode it so that it looks like `/config%23`.

**See:**

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Then when the request comes through into the server, the layer you have added in expressJS would decode the URL from `/config%23` to `/config#` and you replace the `#` char with something unique. Let say `_bbb`, so that the final URL is `/config_bbb` which gets routed to the actual endpoint.

Unfortunately express doesn't like endpoints to have special characters in them, if you don't replace the `#` to be something recognizable then you will find that it doesn't get routed it properly even thou the URL  matches.

Comment: @Z. Danilo Hope this helps. I'm ok with the solution not getting makred as  answered because i'm just throwing ideas here which is kind of a hacky workaround to me.

Comment: @Sanuel-Toh To see the solution to my problem: 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447777/when-i-refresh-the-page-not-the-page-loads-angularjs-nodejs)

also thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: @Z.Danilo Hey no problem at all. Happy to assist, learnt some stuff along the way too.

Comment: I face the same with this URL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: that I want to route using Express in my client lib tests. I can't find a way to tel Express to route %3F (exclamation mark) as a path char and not the param delimiter or a routing regexp special char